# No results when reading from Android database

Tags: android, sqlite

SOLVED. I just can't accept the answer until 2 days has passed. Turned out that sqliteman was reading an old database after all.

I'm trying to read from the database in Android but I don't get any results. The weird thing is that when I run the exact same query on the same database in sqliteman(a sqlite manager) it works perfectly.

My query in my DB-handler class:

```
//exact same as in code
String fetchVaccinesForCountryQuery = 
     "SELECT v._id, v.vname, v.text " +
     "FROM vaccine v, vacc_disease vc " + 
     "WHERE v._id = vc.vaccineId and vc.diseaseId IN (SELECT cd.diseaseId " +
                                                     "FROM country_disease cd " +
                                                     "WHERE cd.countryId = %d)";

//and a version that's a bit easier to read...
String fetchVaccinesForCountryQuery = 
   "SELECT v._id, v.vname, v.text
    FROM vaccine v, vacc_disease vc
    WHERE v._id = vc.vaccineId and vc.diseaseId 
         IN (SELECT cd.diseaseId
         FROM country_disease cd
         WHERE cd.countryId = %d)";

public Cursor fetchVaccinesForCountry(long countryId) {
    String query = String.format(fetchVaccinesForCountryQuery, countryId);
    Log.d("TripDb", "fetchStr: " + query);
    return mDb.rawQuery(query, null);
}
```

I've written an info provider that calls that function:

```
Cursor c = mDb.fetchVaccinesForCountry(countryId);
Log.d("InfoProvider", "numVaccines = " + c.getCount());
```

The logcat string showing the query looks like this:

```
fetchStr: SELECT v._id, v.vname, v.text FROM vaccine v, vacc_disease vc WHERE v._id = vc.vaccineId and vc.diseaseId IN (SELECT cd.diseaseId FROM country_disease cd WHERE cd.countryId = 3)
```

While the Logcat showing number is

```
numVaccines = 0
```

But when I pull the database with adb and run the same query in SqliteMan I get 7 results.  I'm kind of stumped as to why Android doesn't give me 7 results.

Comment: Did you tried to print also the "query" variable and see if the id is correct there?

Comment: Yep, I removed that line from the pasted source code to save space. I copy-paste the query from logcat to sqliteman.

Comment: Please copy and past the query value here

Comment: Output code and result added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So...this is slightly embarrasing. It turned out that when I thought SqliteMan reloaded the database it was using an old file. Once I discovered that I could starting hunting the real error and now everything's working...

Answer (score 0):

I think the only problem from your code might be that you don't take care of the line breaks while defining your query string. I'd suggest you define your query in one line or do it like this:

```
String fetchVaccinesForCountryQuery = 
     "SELECT v._id, v.vname, v.text " +
     "FROM vaccine v, vacc_disease vc " +
     "WHERE v._id = vc.vaccineId and vc.diseaseId " +
     "IN (SELECT cd.diseaseId FROM country_disease cd WHERE cd.countryId = %d)";
```

Comment: Actually that's how it is defined, I tried to clear it up to make it more readable. I'll edit the orignal part in.

Comment: You just forgot a space in every line, this would create a query like "v.textFROM", "vacc_disease vcWHERE".....